# page source not coming for all components in angular universal

Tags: angular, angular5, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have used angular universal for server side rendering. Few of the components are rendered correctly when I see page source of home page but few components shows only angular selectors and not the rendered html. This is happening only with home page. rest of the pages are working as expected.

Comment: Do you get any error server side?

Comment: I am getting `Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Make sure you don't call jQuery if you are server-side (use isPlatformBrowser to check)

Comment: I have found the problem, I have used **ngx-owl-carousel** in my angular app, and **ngx-owl-carousel** does not support angular universal, so the components are not rendering properly, can you suggest me any owl carousel package that supports angular universal ?

Comment: As per the recommendations, don't include it on your server side https://github.com/mujtaba01/ngx-owl-carousel#angular--universal-integration